# Position two last flex items at the end oft the container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a Tabs header component and need the last two items to be positioned at the right. My code looks like this

```
li:nth-last-child(1),
  li:nth-last-child(2) {
    color: #c2c2c2;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

The last item(1) is justified to the end but the second item(2) is being positioned close to the center of the container. Is there a better way to fix this using this approach?

Comment: margin-left comes in the way for the very last item. it shoud not be  auto for that one

Comment: you need it auto for one item that will push the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `margin-left: auto;` only on `li:nth-last-child(2)`.
`margin-left: auto;` pushes the item and the following ones to the right.
Here is a quick [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-z-index-and-auto-margins-work-in-flexbox/) regarding flex and margins.

Updated code :

```
li:nth-last-child(1),
li:nth-last-child(2) {
    color: #c2c2c2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

li:nth-last-child(2) {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```